# Python, Нужно добавить все объекты в список

Tags: python, list

Есть код:

```
class Transport(object):
    def  __init__ (self, s, c, m):
        self.speed = s 
        self.color = c 
        self.made = m
    def  __str__ (self):
        s="Скорость:" + str(self.speed) + ",цвет:" + self.color + ", производитель:" + self.made + "\n"
        s=str(s)
        return s 
    def go(self):
        print("Начинает движение ", self.made) 
    def stop(self):
        print("Остановка ",self.made)
transport1 = Transport(20, "blue", "Forward") 
transport2 = Transport(180, "white", "Ford") 
transport3 = Transport(100, "red", "MA3")
print(transport1) 
print(transport2) 
print(transport3) 
transport1.go() 
transport2.go() 
transport3.stop()
```

Нужно добавить все объекты (`Transport1`, `Transport2`, `Transport3`) в список и вывести этот список.
Когда я пишу `spisok = Transpor1, Transport2, Transport3`, то выводится

```
[<__main__.Transport object at 0x000002549E21C8B0>, <__main__.Transport object at 0x000002549E21CA30>, <__main__.Transport object at 0x000002549E21C880>]
```

Добрые люди, помогите

Comment: что вы хотите увидеть при `выводе` списка ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Они добавились корректно, просто отображение классов в списке не настроено. Для этого можно переписать дандер `__repr__`

```
class Transport(object):
    def  __init__ (self, s, c, m):
        self.speed = s 
        self.color = c 
        self.made = m
    def  __str__ (self):
        s="Скорость:" + str(self.speed) + ",цвет:" + self.color + ", производитель:" + self.made + "\n"
        s=str(s)
        return s 
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Скорость: {self.speed}, цвет: + {self.color} +  производитель: {self.made}"

transport1 = Transport(20, "blue", "Forward") 
transport2 = Transport(180, "white", "Ford") 
transport3 = Transport(100, "red", "MA3")

a = [transport3, transport2, transport1, ]

print(a) #[Объект Transport MA3, Объект Transport Ford, Объект Transport Forward]
```

`__str__` - возвращает строковое представление объекта. Срабатывает в момент вызова `print()` или `str()`

`__repr__` - срабатывает в момент вызова одноимённой функции.

Есть мнение, что `__str__` - это дандер для написания "приятного" чтения для пользователя, а `__repr__` - для внутреннего представления. При этом `__repr__` может заменить `__str__` в случае отстутствия последнего

Comment: Нужно чтобы выводились все данные об одном объекте т. е. должно выводится Скорость:20,цвет:blue, производитель:Forward, Скорость:180,цвет:white, производитель:Ford, Скорость:100,цвет:red, производитель:MA3

Comment: Это всё можно сделать в дандере __repr__
В ответе я подправил под ваш комментарий

Comment: `repr` используется в интерактивном питоне, например, для репрезентации объекта когда его имя вводят, без `print`